# Is this design pattern(extended view helper) acceptable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The class(ViewHelper) that takes care of the user input and sending it back to the model is getting bigger and I want to create an extended class(ExtendedViewHelper) that inherit the ViewHeper class. The problem is that I don't know if it's following pure OO-design. Here comes a class diagram:
[image: Class Diagram]

Now some code to simplify it even more:

```
//ViewHelper class
public ViewHelper(View tempForm)
{
 xForm = tempForm;
 //some more code
}

//ExtendedViewHelper class
public ExtendedViewHelper(View yForm): base(xForm)
{
   //some more code 
}

//And the View
public View()
{
  //Instantiating the object to ExtendedViewHelper
  viewHelper = new ExtendedViewHelper(this);
  //Calling method from class ViewHelper
  viewHelper.OnButtonClicked();
  //and from ExtendedViewHelper
  ((ExtendedViewHelper)viewHelper).OnSecondBtnClicked();
}
```

Would you say that this is a good solution to the problem(if it's even considered as a problem) or am I overengineering things? Is there a better solution or should I only use Viewhelper(~700 row of code)?

Comment: Any class that's called "ViewHelper" probably already has too much stuff going on in it (having hundreds of lines of code is another good indicator). Your "solution" is anything but. Going by rule of thumb, what you probably should be doing is split up your class into about 5-10 other classes _that don't reference each other, because they likely don't have to_.

Comment: @Cubic Are you missing a word in "Your "solution" is anything but"? So it's not a good solution? I don't really like the idea when there is a bunch of "has a"-relaion" between the View and the helper-classes. But I may be wrong. Please tell me then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solutions are the ones that create the least amount of coupling and the simplest possible classes.

Your View currently depends on it's ViewHelper. This is acceptable.

However, if your View ever casts something as an ExtendedViewHelper, it is then coupled to two objects, which could give the system two reasons to change and two places where things can break. This violates the Single Responsibility Principle.

The one role of the View should be to display things. It should not be concerned with where the system functionality exists or how to process commands.

The ViewHelper also should have one role. It should act as the go-between from the View to the Controller/Services/Functionality Layer. The ViewHelper should never have implementation details of how any operations are performed.

So a better solution looks like this:

```
public View()
{
  //Instantiating the object to ExtendedViewHelper
  viewHelper = new ExtendedViewHelper(this);
  //Calling method from class ViewHelper
  viewHelper.OnButtonClicked();
  //and from ExtendedViewHelper
  viewHelper.OnSecondBtnClicked();
}

//OldViewHelper Constructor
public ViewHelper(View tempForm, OldFunctionalityService oldService)
{
     xForm = tempForm;
     xService = oldService;
}

//First Button Implementation Code
public void OnButtonClicked()
{
    xService.DoStuff();
}

//NewViewHelper Constructor
public ViewHelper(View tempForm, OldFunctionalityService oldService, NewFunctionalityService newService)
{
     xForm = tempForm;
     xService = oldService;
     xNewService = newService;
}

//Second Button Implementation Code
public void OnSecondBtnClicked()
{
    xNewService.DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually my controller works as a communication layer whereas ViewHelper performs all the eventhandlers and the input validation. If I have understood you correctly, I should not cast to ExtendedViewHelper but instead instantiate the object to ExtendedViewHelper? And my View only takes care of displaying and creating properties. I really like the idea of service- and functionality layers. Unfortunately I have never implemented them. Do you know any good site about this topic?

Comment: Most of this is related to architectural concerns. Here are a couple of possible resources I could recommend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658117.aspx   http://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Martin/dp/0321127420   http://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-7/show

Comment: From the way I've learned, the most important principles are SOLID. They are most applicable at the class level, but they also work at the component level, just in a somewhat different way. http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod